# Transition ease-in-out moving on page load

Tags: php, html, css, transition

On my website, the search box on the top moves and changes right when you load the page on Google Chrome. It doesn't do this on other pages even though the header on the top has the same HTML and CSS code. Can someone look at the code to see what's wrong?
And also, how can I change the URL to from something like http://www.example.com/user?u=username to http://www.example.com/username and have it load the same page?

Answer (score 1):

First, you're asking 2 different questions:

- How do I make this CSS Transition run on page load?
- How do I change my links from parameters to paths?

The CSS transition?  I don't see any transitions.  If you're asking about the opacity, your `tos` and `user` pages use two different stylesheets, `formstyle.css` and `style.css`.  The opacity of `style.css` is set to 1 and the opacity for `formstyle.css` is set to 0.8.  And I don't see any searchbars.

For changing paths, look into .htaccess.  It is what configures how browsers view files on your server.

EDIT: You fixed the avatar issue.

Comment: I already tried putting multiple different code for the htaccess but none of them worked. Can you write one that works with the way my website is set up? And there should be a search box on the top bar.

Comment: Oh, I realized that you have to login to see it. Could you look at the code of it then? Or if you don't mind, make an account to see the search?